# Ericsson Cycle - How to Calculate Heat Transfer

Tags: thermodynamics

Let's consider a Ericsson Cycle with working body an ideal gas, e.g.: 
https://www.theengineerspost.com/ericsson-cycle/

I still haven't figured out how to calculate the heat transfer between process $1\rightarrow 2$ yet.

Comment: What is your thinking so far?  What values are you supposed to assume are given?

Comment: You don’t know how to determine heat transfer for a constant pressure process?